# Generally non-integer winding number of curve given by $e^{2\pi i(f(t)+g(t)i)}$ for arbitrary f, g & $t$ $\in$ $[t_1,t_2]$ seems to not always be real

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(t)=g(t)+h(t)i$

Let $F(z)=e^{2\pi iz}$

Let $C$ be the curve traced out by $F(f(t))$ for $t$ $\in$ $[t_1,t_2]$

After graphing numerous examples, I noticed that - judging solely by appearance - the winding number of $C$ with respect to $0$ is always $g(t_2)-g(t_1)$

In trying to prove this, I ended up with the winding number coming out to

$$\int_{t_1}^{t_2}(g'(t)+h'(t)i)dt$$

If I'm indeed going about this correctly, would someone kindly please explain why the winding number isn't guaranteed to be a real number?

Or if I'm going about this misguidedly, would someone please explain what my misunderstanding seems to be?

Comment: Usually winding number is reserved for closed curves. Are you putting restrictions on $g$ and $h$ to ensure that? Otherwise, what is your definition of winding number?

Comment: @S.C. whichever definition allows for non-closed curves and allows for non-integer winding numbers

Comment: You don't have to go so far as to require $g(t_1) = g(t_2)$, you can merely have that $F(f(t))$ starts and ends at the same point. That fixes $h$ to starting and ending at the same point, but $g$ can end at a point higher or lower by an integer amount.

Comment: Is it simply the case that the winding number for $C$ is not well-defined unless $C$ is closed?

Comment: What if we choose $f(t)=e^{it}+i$ and $t$ $\in$ $[-\pi/2,3\pi/2]$. Then $C$ is indeed closed, and yet the computed winding number is not a real number

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting $0$ for the integral of $g'(t) + h'(t)i$, assuming $g(t) = \cos(t)$ and h(t) = $\sin(t) + 1$

Comment: oh yes I double-checked and it is zero. My mistake, apologies

Comment: also, I should have been more careful in the first place to check that the logarithmic derivative method only works for closed curves. This all could have been avoided. Lesson learned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to define the winding number about a point for non-closed curves is by considering just the angle made from the point to the curve. As with closed curves, this angle function lifts to a unique continuous function $\theta : [t_1, t_2] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\theta(t_1) = \arg(F(f(t_1)))$ where $\arg$ is the argument (angle) function. Then the winding number can be defined by $\frac{\theta(t_2) - \theta(t_1)}{2\pi}$.

Now assuming $g$ is continuous and both $f$ and $g$ are real-valued, $2\pi g(t)$ is
a possible argument, but might not match up with $\arg(F(f(t_1))$ at $t_1$. We can fix that just by adding an appropriate constant, yielding
$\theta(t) = 2\pi (g(t) - g(t_1)) + \arg(F(f(t_1)))$.

Thus, the winding number is $\frac{\theta(t_2) - \theta(t_1)}{2\pi} = (g(t_2) - g(t_1) + \frac{\arg(F(f(t_1)))}{2\pi}) - (g(t_1) - g(t_1) + \frac{\arg(F(f(t_1)))}{2\pi}) = g(t_2) - g(t_1)$.

The problem you may have run into is that you're using the logarithmic derivative to calculate the winding number. This only works for closed curves. Indeed, if you just ensure that $h(t_1) = h(t_2)$, then your integral works out to $g(t_2) - g(t_1)$ as expected. To give an explicit example, consider the curve $\gamma(t) = t^2$ for $t$ in $[1, 2]$. This curve moves straight away from the origin, so intuitively its "winding number" around $0$ should be $0$ since the angle is always $0$. But the logarithmic derivative is $2t/t^2 = 2/t$, so the integral of that over the curve is $2\log(2) \neq 0$.

The reason the logarithmic derivative works for closed curves is that if you write a curve $\gamma(t)$ as $r(t) e^{\theta(t) i}$, with $r(t)$ and $\theta(t)$ differentiable, the logarithmic derivative is $\frac{r'(t)}{r(t)} + \theta'(t) i$. The integral of the second part gives the desired winding number (times $2 \pi i$), while the integral of the first part is $\log(r(t_1)) - \log(r(t_2))$. This first part is zero when the curve is closed but more generally when the curve starts and ends at the same magnitude.